# Pre-C++11 SFINAE in combination with ADL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer, tr1

I have to deal with Google Protobug packets defined in various namespaces:

```
// Those are generated classes
/// @file server.pb.h
namespace Server {
    class ServerMsg1 : public ::google::protobuf::Message { 
    };
    class ServerMsg2 : public ::google::protobuf::Message { 
    };
    // etc..
}
/// @file client.pb.h
namespace Unit {
    class UnitMsg1 : public ::google::protobuf::MessageLite { 
    };
    // etc..
}
```

The idea is, that `printProtoData`would be able to find printData in apparopriate namespace or it would choose the overload that uses a superclass of its argument (`Message` or `MessageLite`).

while I have certain generalised classes which use them as components within global namespace.
Provided that I have a function\adapter (agnostic of namespace, thanks to ADL), but it must be very general to support non-Protobuf types:

```
///@file packet.h

// No printData function is defined, so it would be searched in terms of ADL
template <class PacketType>
void printProtoData(const PacketType &p) {
    printData(p);
}
```

And an abstract interface class for data with a CRTP as a mix-in interface (for reasons)

```
// simplified user class
template<typename T, typename M>
class ProtoContainer : AbstractContainer {
    M msg;
public:
    // cannot be virtual, it vould instantiate printProtoData immediately
    void print() { ::printProtoData(this->msg); }
};
```

And each namespace got a constellation of functions to print them, but some may be missing, temporarily or intentionally:

```
#include "packet.h"
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "server.pb.h"
#include "client.pb.h"
namespace Server {
    using printFunctions::printData;
    void printData(const ServerMsg1& msg);
    void printData(const ServerMsg2& msg);
}
namespace Unit {
    using printFunctions::printData;
    void printData(const UnitMsg1& msg);
}

// An example of user for data, it instantiates printProtoData
struct ProtoUser : ProtoContainer<ProtoUser, Server::ServerMsg1 > {
   // ...
};
```

To avoid errors, I want to define fallback functions which would take ANY type of Protobuf message, so I defined those and added `using printFunctions::printData;` to respective namespaces:

```
/// @file wrapper.h
#include <iostream>

// Can I do better than this?
namespace google {
    namespace protobuf { 
    class MessageLite;
    class Message; 
    }
}

// Scary SFINAE syntax because this should compile in TR1 (VS2010)
namespace printFunctions {
    template <typename Msg> 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<::google::protobuf::MessageLite, Msg>::value>::type
        printData(const Msg& msg)
    {
        std::cout << "------------ " << msg.GetTypeName();
    }

    template <typename Msg> 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<::google::protobuf::Message, Msg>::value>::type
        printData(const Msg & msg)
    {
        std::cout << "------------ " << msg.GetTypeName();
        std::cout << msg.DebugString();
    }
}
```

This works in Vs2017+. Is this portable, i.e.

- Is this correct SFINAE style for Vs2010 (incomplete C++11)?
- Is this approach portable to GCC and clang?

VisualStudio's compiler is  rather lenient and doesn't respect ADL limitations (it expands to other namespaces, including global one), so "it works here" doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Why are you limited to some old Visual Studio compiler? Why not just use a more recent version and *actually* use C++11, if you're using C++11 features anyway? Also, what's keeping you from compiling it as C++11 with GCC and clang? This would make it trivially portable to those compilers, because your code is valid C++11.

Comment: @JanSchultke I don't ask why our hardware department is limited to VS6  and some 15 year old CodeWarrior version. Just is reality of certain markets. My target range is fromVS2010 to  VS2017, GCC 4.7 to gcc 10 because thats commercial production targets we use, that's all. Upgrading that requires 12-13-digit numbers (in USD).

Comment: @JanSchultke if it's completely valid.. eah. My concern was ADL. VS ,all versions of VS I raget allow leave those functions in global namespace, heh